# Extra white space in dropdown with VirtualScroll true in ng-select angular component

Tags: angular, ng-options, angular-ngselect

[image]

Extra space is showing in ng-select dropdown when I use virtuallScroll property as true.

**Reproducible example**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuvic8?file=styles.css

Comment: You can apply patch and give fix height to total-padding class. 
like ::ng-deep .total-padding { height: 150px }

Comment: I have the same issue. Couldn't find a fix. I use ng-select ^6.0.0. I'd appreciate if someone can provide a fix/workaround for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Issue is yet to be resolved by the ng-select library team.

The similar kind of issue is https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1402 for your reference.